# Metrics not displaying when running model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am working my way through an ML example in Google Colabs. The documentation says that when I run model.fit, the loss and accuracy metrics are displayed. I am not seeing any loss or accuracy metric.

I have added `accuracy` as a metric in model.compile

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing. [image]

How do I get the loss and accuracy metrics to be displayed when I am fitting the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [verbose flag](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) and set it to 2 to display 1 line per epoch or 1 for a progress bar.

Answer (score -1):

```
import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(5, 6)))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

x_data = np.random.random((32, 5, 6))
y_data = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(32,5,1))

model.fit(x=x_data, y=y_data, batch_size=16, epochs=3)
```

```
Use tf.cast instead.
Epoch 1/3
32/32 [==============================] - 1s 20ms/step - loss: 9.9664
Epoch 2/3
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 293us/step - loss: 9.9537
Epoch 3/3
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 164us/step - loss: 9.9425
```

I hope it solves your problem.